# Attempt to call field 'registersave' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I'm making a lua script for DeSmuMe, a Nintendo Ds Emulator. I wanted to use this command to save a value on save state: savestate.registersave(function() return frame end)
But the emulator gives me this error: :50: attempt to call field 'registersave' (a nil value). Why? How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this function in any working script?

I checked the source code of DeSmuMe on Sourceforge.

In a file called lua-engine.cpp (last changed 2015-09-15, so after the latest release) I found this:

```
static const struct luaL_reg statelib [] =
{
    {"create", state_create},
    {"save", state_save},
    {"load", state_load},
#ifndef PUBLIC_RELEASE
    {"verify", state_verify}, // for desync catching
#endif
    // TODO
    //{"loadscriptdata", state_loadscriptdata},
    //{"savescriptdata", state_savescriptdata},
    //{"registersave", state_registersave},
    //{"registerload", state_registerload},
    {NULL, NULL}
};
```

So obviously  `savestate.registersave` hasn't made it into the Lua interface yet. So you can't use it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding any emulator where that exact function has been implemented. Anyway, it's possible to implement a hotkey and make savestates yourself in script, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Uh so this is what causes this error...thanks for your answers!